# Derive name based on a substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to get the label from `df B` based on a sub-string in a column of `df A`.

**Question**

Is there a way to do this without using Loop?

**dataframe A:**

```
original string:

1. test1(arizona)     
2. NJtest2
```

**dataframe B:**

```
keyword          Label

1. test1            First Cycle Test
2. test2            Second Cycle Test
```

**Output:**

```
Original         Target

1. test1(arizona)  First Cycle Test
2. NJtest2         Second Cycle Test
```

Comment: Use `str.extract` and `merge`.

Comment: I'm not sure sandips datraframes have leading numbers, but that doesn't change the answer I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.extract` + `merge`:

```
df1
              Col
0  test1(arizona)
1         NJtest2

df2
  keyword              Label
0   test1   First Cycle Test
1   test2  Second Cycle Test
```

```
p = '(?P<Key>.*(?P<keyword>{}).*)'.format('|'.join(df2.keyword))

df1.Col.str.extract(p, expand=True)\
            .merge(df2).drop('keyword', 1)

              Key              Label
0  test1(arizona)   First Cycle Test
1         NJtest2  Second Cycle Test
```

The regex pattern extracts the keyword as well as the complete string, which makes the merge painless.

Comment: Thanks. It looks a little more complex to a novice like me, compared to the one by Wen. However I like this one too and keep it for future.

Comment: @sandipsanyal I'm guessing this should be fast.

Comment: Hi Coldspeed, yes you are right. This is way faster than the other one. I am marking this one as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`fuzzywuzzy` + `apply`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['test1(arizona)', 'NJtest2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['test1', 'test2'],'col2':['s1','s2']})
from fuzzywuzzy import process
df2['New']=df2.keyword.apply(lambda x : [process.extract(x, df1.col1, limit=1)][0][0][0])
df2
Out[133]: 
  col2 keyword             New
0   s1   test1  test1(arizona)
1   s2   test2         NJtest2
```

Comment: Thanks Wen. Looks like this is exactly what I needed. Cool.

Comment: @sandipsanyal yw~ :-)

Comment: Wen, this one was taking way too much time, however the one suggested by coldspeed is really fast. Please see that one. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused here. You are only looking to replace the keyword column with the original string? Then this should be sufficient:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'original string': ['test1(arizona)', 'NJtest2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['test1', 'test2','test3']
                    ,'label':['First Cycle Test','Second Cycle Test','Third Cycle Test']})

def func(x):
    find = [i for i in df1['original string'].tolist() if x in i]
    if find:
        return find[0]
    else:
        return "None"

df2.keyword = df2.keyword.apply(func)

df2 = df2.rename(columns=dict(keyword='Orginal',label='Target'))
```

Returns:

```
          Orginal             Target
0  test1(arizona)   First Cycle Test
1         NJtest2  Second Cycle Test
2            None   Third Cycle Test
```